# generic parser return hash-map and not Pojo

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have this code (A):

```
JsonFileHandler<Device> jsonFileHandlerDevice;
final List<Device> devicesList = jsonFileHandlerDevice.getList();
```

and

```
class JsonFileHandler<T>:

@Override
public List<T> getList() {
    List<T> t = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    if (!file.exists()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            t = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<T>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

and this code (B):

```
@Override
public List<Device> getList() {
    List<Device> t = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    if (!file.exists()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            t = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<Device>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

and this json file:

```
[ {
  "mobileOs" : "ios",
  "osVersion" : 4.2,
  "allocatedPort" : 0,
  "hasSim" : false,
  "uuid" : "uuid2",
  "wazers" : [ {
    "email" : null,
    "emailPassword" : null,
    "first" : null,
    "last" : null,
    "driverPhone" : null,
    "riderPhone" : null,
    "username" : null,
    "password" : null,
    "workEmail" : null,
    "car" : null,
    "model" : null,
    "color" : null,
    "plate" : null,
    "obId" : null
  } ],
  "riders" : [ {
    "email" : null,
    "emailPassword" : null,
    "first" : null,
    "last" : null,
    "driverPhone" : null,
    "riderPhone" : null,
    "username" : null,
    "password" : null,
    "workEmail" : null,
    "car" : null,
    "model" : null,
    "color" : null,
    "plate" : null,
    "obId" : null
  }, {
    "email" : null,
    "emailPassword" : null,
    "first" : null,
    "last" : null,
    "driverPhone" : null,
    "riderPhone" : null,
    "username" : null,
    "password" : null,
    "workEmail" : null,
    "car" : null,
    "model" : null,
    "color" : null,
    "plate" : null,
    "obId" : null
  } ]
} ]
```

The code parses OK only while executing code (B)

and when running code (A) we get a hash-map instead of of Pojo `Device`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you can get the generic type of your class somehow via Spring or whatever you are using as an IoC container, so for simplicity I am passing the type via constructor. That being said, one solution I can currently think of for your problem is the following:

```
class JsonFileHandler<T> {

    private File file = new File("/Users/dambros/Desktop/test");
    private final Class<T> type;

    public JsonFileHandler(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        List<T> t;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametrizedType(ArrayList.class, List.class, type);
                t = mapper.readValue(file, javaType);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

}
```

Using a call like below will return a List of your POJOs instead of a HashMap:

```
JsonFileHandler<Device> jsonFileHandlerDevice = new JsonFileHandler<>(Device.class);
final List<Device> devicesList = jsonFileHandlerDevice.getList();
```

Obs.: The mapper configs are just there to avoid having to write all the entries on the JSON and making the test easier.

Comment: why does my code works for `new TypeReference<List<Device>>()` and not for `new TypeReference<List<T>>()`

Comment: The problem is with type erasure. Since T is just a type variable, it is like saying `T extends Object`. Because of that Jackson will bind `JSONObject` as `Map`, unless you indicate the actual class type. In your exemple, when you say `new TypeReference<List<Device>>()` that is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: how can I replace `new TypeReference<List<Device>>()` with general generic?

Comment: You can't use it the way you did with TypeReference and I've showed you above how it should be. The only thing that should be different for you, is how you get the generic type since you are using dependency injection.